CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH is ignored for a library when generating a package
I'm creating a DEB package with cpack and want to include opencv libraries. Since some opencv libraries depend on each other, I want to set rpath for them so the linker can find them. Here's what I do:
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)

install(TARGETS
    myapp
    RUNTIME
        COMPONENT App
        DESTINATION "."
    LIBRARY
        COMPONENT App
        DESTINATION "lib"
)

find_package(OpenCV 4.7 REQUIRED)
get_target_property(OpenCV_imgcodecs_INSTALL_PATH opencv_imgcodecs LOCATION)
get_target_property(OpenCV_core_INSTALL_PATH opencv_core LOCATION)
get_target_property(OpenCV_imgproc_INSTALL_PATH opencv_imgproc LOCATION)

install(FILES
    ${OpenCV_imgcodecs_INSTALL_PATH}
    ${OpenCV_core_INSTALL_PATH}
    ${OpenCV_imgproc_INSTALL_PATH}
    COMPONENT App
    DESTINATION lib
)

When I inspect the files in after the installation, or in the temporary directory with readelf -d binary, the RPATH section is empty both for my executable and for libraries.
But if I change the properties of my executable:
set_target_properties(myapp PROPERTIES
    INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE
     INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN/lib"
)

I can see the settings were applied:
$ readelf -d myapp

...
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [$ORIGIN/lib]
...

But I can't do the same for the opencv dependencies. This section has no effect:
set_target_properties(opencv_imgcodecs PROPERTIES
    INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE
    INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN"
)

As a result, when I install and run myapp, the linker can't find the necessary libs.

Setting of variable CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH affects only on targets created after it. As for IMPORTED targets, like opencv_imgcodecs, CMake doesn't modify their .so files. So the properties like INSTALL_RPATH are useless for those targets.

As @Tsyvarev pointed out:

Setting of variable CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH affects only on targets created after it

And indeed, from the Docs for INSTALL_RPATH target property:

This property is initialized by the value of the variable CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH if it is set when a target is created.

To change the RPATH of imported targets on linux, one of the solutions would be to run patchelf. There're two steps to do that when creating a package:

Use a CPACK_INSTALL_SCRIPTS script to get the name of the temporary directory where the artifacts are installed before packing. For example:
set(pathToTemporaryInstallDir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX})

Use a CPACK_PRE_BUILD_SCRIPTS script to run a COMMAND to patch an executable. For example:
execute_process(COMMAND patchelf --set-rpath "$ORIGIN" "${pathToTemporaryInstallDir}/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.7.0")


